# How to scroll listview by pressing buttons

Tags: android

I have a requirement that：

I need to display one `ListView` and at the bottom of my view I need to show two buttons (`Scroll Up` & `Scroll down`).

When I `click` on my scroll buttons my List should scroll accordingly.

For this I have used

```
 android:scrollbars="none"
```

In my  element and in my java code I'm increasing or decreasing list view position by below code

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (view == scrollupbtn) {
        if(listViewPosition >= 1)
            list_view.smoothScrollToPosition(-- listViewPosition);
    } else if (view == scrolldownbtn) {
        list_view.smoothScrollToPosition(++ listViewPosition);
    }
}
```

The above code able to scroll my list but It is not showing default selector on the current position of my item.

And I need to give complete scrolling control to my buttons now I am able to scroll my list by swiping also.

Please let me know what can be done to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) to change the currently selected item.
To disable scroll on swiping you'll probably need to inherit your own class from ListView and override [onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Comment: there may be a solution with using focusableInTouchMode to disable swiping